# snipMate: Insert file extension

Tags: vim, snipmate

I have a snipMate snippet that prints header comments for C and C++ files, and I would like it to print the full filename, as in "File: main.cpp".

The documentation says:

> With no arguments, the default filename without an extension is returned; ...

but doesn't say how to get the extension, if it's possible.

I tried `'&filetype'` (with backticks instead of ') which does insert a filetype, but not the right one: It gives "cpp" for .h files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `:function Filename` would have shown you how it's implemented by snipMate. It makes use of `expand()` and `:help filename-modifiers`. To get the current file, use `%`; the `:t` strips off any path.

```
snippet filename
        File: `expand('%:t')`
```

Comment: Where would I do :function Filename? vim says there's no such function and I can't find where it's implemented by snipMate.

Comment: You need to use snipMate once before it's defined, as snipMate uses the autoload functionality; the function is in `~/.vim/autoload/snipMate.vim`.

Answer (score 1):

You should post the snippet in question.

Anyway, there are more than one way to get the filename with the extension. You could use `bufname('%')` or `expand('%:t')`.